# Connect to an oracle instance from another oracle instance on different servers

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, dblink

How to create a DB link between two Oracle instances on different servers with different IPs. let say A (10g with e.g. 192.168.1.1) and B (11g with e.g. 192.168.1.2)  are two instances. I want to access the data in instance A from the instance B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People usually edit TNSNAMES.ORA and include database B alias in there, and then

```
create database link dblink
  connect to username_on_B
  identified by password_on_B
  using 'database_B_tnsnames_ora_alias';
```

Or, without TNSNAMES.ORA, something like this:

```
create database link dblink
 connect to username_on_B
 identified by password_on_B
 using '192.168.1.2:1521/dbB_service_name';
                    ----
                    port
```

Comment: Thank you dear Littlefoot. Worked! But there is a problem. I'm using it in Oracle Apex. When I want to use it with my views this error happens : ora-04052 error occurred when looking up remote object. But it works correctly with my tables. Where is the problem?!

Comment: @Professor Please look at the compatibility matrix for connecting from lower to higher version. Be specific about the exact version up to 4 decimals. It might be issue due to lower version where DB_LINK is created and trying to connect to a higher version.

Comment: Hello, @Lalit! Nice to see you! BTW, as of this question: I don't expect any problems in 10g and 11g connection; they are close enough. If it were several versions apart, then yes - one might need a "bridge" database in between, the one that supports DB links between both of databases.

Comment: Hello @Littlefoot! Good to see you too. You are right, 10g and 11g are compatible, I think it was 9i to 11g which usually had this error. OP marked as accepted so he probably got through the error now.